# How to split data in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have dataset like

```
Period from  Customer Period 2
300            A        350
351            B        null
```

i want to split the data like

```
Period from  Customer Period 2
300            A        NULL
301            A        NULL
302            A        NULL
303            A        NULL
304            A
```

Comment: What is the `period 2` for 304; and why does it stop there? Presumably you've just truncated the output? - but it would have been better to pick a smaller range and show it complete, and at least show what happens with 351 (and beyond?!). Are you trying to change/replace the data in a table, or is this just going to be the output of a query? As a hint, look up hierarchical queries and recursive subquery factoring.

Comment: period 2 for 304 will be null, same goes for A till 350. All period should be null

Comment: I am not able to create the query to achieve this output, can you able to help me pls

Comment: And what happened with customer "B"? Not included in the output because her period_2 is `null`?

Comment: Customer B Period from should be 351 and period to should be null

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hierarchy query` as follows:

```
select column_value AS PERIOD_FROM,
       CUSTOMER,
       NULL AS PERIOD_TO
from YOUR_TABLE cross join
     table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                         connect by level <= PERIOD_TO - PERIOD_FROM + 1
                        ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
order by column_value;
```

Comment: Can i put some constraint in this like where clause. If yes where should i put

Comment: before `order by` and after `) as sys.odcinumberlist))`

Comment: it giving output like this: 1 A null
2 A null
3 A null

Comment: I don't think you need the `table/multiset` thing. A simple `cross join (select level from dual ...)` should achieve the same thing.

Comment: what about the data like `row1 -- 300-350, row2 -- 351-360, row3 -- 361-null` in that case a different number of rows need to be generated so used the `table/multiset`

Comment: please replace the `PERIOD_TO` and `PERIOD_FROM` with your table's original column names.

Comment: i replaced that sir

Comment: `connect by level <= PERIOD_TO - PERIOD_FROM + 1` -- here also?? can you please share the actual query that you are executing?